# Make this code snippet better

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a program that has the following code:

```
foreach (string section in DataAccessLayer.AcceptedSections)
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case "Section1":
            Console.WriteLine("Section 1");
            break;
        case "Section2":
            Console.WriteLine("Section 2");
            break;
        case "Section3":
            Console.WriteLine("Section 3");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default section");
            break;
    }                    
}
```

**Is there anyway i can do what this code does without providing the section's string again within the case?** The DataAccessLayer.AcceptedSections is dynamic and i don't want to have to add another section case to my code, rebuild and redeploy every time a new section comes on board. It's Friday and my mind is not working very well.

**For Example:**
I don't want to add the following code when Section 4 gets added to the database:

```
case "Section4":
    Console.WriteLine("Section 4");
     break;
```

Comment: what does your `AcceptedSections` table look like?

Comment: Belongs on CodeReview.StackExchange.Com

Comment: They were all great answers, I +1 on all answers, but for my case, the dictionary worked best because i'm able to attach the method i want executed on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a `Dictionary<string,Action<T>>` that is keyed by `section`. This will completely replace the switch statement.

Invoke the corresponding action:

```
foreach (string section in DataAccessLayer.AcceptedSections)
{
    myActionsDictionary[section]();
}
```

Comment: really? down vote? This isn't a bad option though it's not dynamic. +1

Comment: a) I'm not the downvoter. b) However, does this not still present a similar challenge as before? You still would need to see that "Section4" and an appropriate action was registered to the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

If the string is always "SectionN", you could just handle it directly:

```
if (section.StartsWith("Section"))
    Console.WriteLine(section.Insert(7, " "));
else
    Console.WriteLine("Default Section");
```

Comment: +1 for StartsWith/Insert.  I'm always learning something on StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 1):

If this is all data-driven I suggest you just return some other display value from the database along with that identifier string

Table **AcceptedSections**

```
Name = "Section1"
DisplayName = "Section 1"
```

Then you can just just return the `DisplayName`

---

If it is not you'll have to handle this like you're doing now or you could create an enum with an attribute for display:

```
public enum AcceptedSections
{
    [Description("Default Section")]
    Default,
    [Description("Section 1")]
    Section1,
    [Description("Section 2")]
    Section2,
    [Description("Section 3")]
    Section3,
    [Description("Section 4")]
    Section4
}
// writing this made me kind woozy... what a terrible enum
```

which will allow you to write something like this:

```
foreach (AcceptedSections section in AcceptedSections.GetValues())
{
    Console.WriteLine(section.GetDescription());
}
```

where `GetDescription()` is a simple method that returns that custom attribute on the enum

Comment: You had me until the edit. The first approach to make it data driven provides maximum flexibility for changes to the display value without having to affect the code (absent the initial change to incorporate the additional field, obviously). However, adding an enum once again presents the same challenge he is trying to escape: updating the code each time a section is added to the database.

Comment: @Anthony yeah, just presenting a slightly more manageable option. Managing an enum is better than managing that switch statement IMHO. But yes, the data-driven option is preferred.

Comment: Perhaps, but ultimately, it still involves rolling a new version of an application, library, or whatever with each modification of data. Seems problematic.

Comment: Agreed, but what choice does OP have if it's not tied to the database or some external source? what choice...